# Replacing a value with user defined function in grouped data

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I come to an issue that replacing a value with another if the condition is met. I use my own function `data_manip` that I can assign or add any other condition when needed.

However, when I try to use this `data_manip` function it changes all the values within that group with the assigned value. But the other values in that particular group do not met with this condition.

Here is what I tried,

```
df <- data.frame(percent = c(0.6, 0.7,1, 0.5,0.5,1,0.4,0.6,1), 
                 type = rep(c("good", "bad","ugly"),each=3), smoke=rep(c('Visky','Wine','Wine'),3),
                 sex=rep(c('male','male','female'),3))

> df
  percent type smoke    sex
1     0.6 good Visky   male
2     0.7 good  Wine   male
3     1.0 good  Wine female
4     0.5  bad Visky   male
5     0.5  bad  Wine   male
6     1.0  bad  Wine female
7     0.4 ugly Visky   male
8     0.6 ugly  Wine   male
9     1.0 ugly  Wine female


data_manip <- function(x,gr){
  if(grepl('goo|ug',gr)&&x<1){
    x[x==0.6] <- 1
  }
    else
  x
}

df%>%
  group_by(type)%>%
  mutate(percent_new=data_manip(percent,type))
```

gives

```
# A tibble: 9 x 5
# Groups:   type [3]
  percent   type  smoke    sex percent_new
    <dbl> <fctr> <fctr> <fctr>       <dbl>
1     0.6   good  Visky   male         1.0
2     0.7   good   Wine   male         1.0
3     1.0   good   Wine female         1.0
4     0.5    bad  Visky   male         0.5
5     0.5    bad   Wine   male         0.5
6     1.0    bad   Wine female         1.0
7     0.4   ugly  Visky   male         1.0
8     0.6   ugly   Wine   male         1.0
9     1.0   ugly   Wine female         1.0
```

I would like to keep original `percent` values if the condition is not for them.

Expected output

```
 # A tibble: 9 x 5
    # Groups:   type [3]
      percent   type  smoke    sex percent_new
        <dbl> <fctr> <fctr> <fctr>       <dbl>
    1     0.6   good  Visky   male         1.0
    2     0.7   good   Wine   male         0.7
    3     1.0   good   Wine female         1.0
    4     0.5    bad  Visky   male         0.5
    5     0.5    bad   Wine   male         0.5
    6     1.0    bad   Wine female         1.0
    7     0.4   ugly  Visky   male         0.4
    8     0.6   ugly   Wine   male         1.0
    9     1.0   ugly   Wine female         1.0
```

Comment: try `ifelse()` in `mutate()`, `ifelse()` is a vectorized function.

Comment: or use `sapply()` in mutate() anything that returns a vectorized output can be used in mutate to replace or create new values.

Comment: @fhlgood Got the same result with `sapply`;(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current `data_manip` function does not seem to be vectorized as it uses `if (cond) { ... } else { ... }`, which generally only checks a single value and is probably defaulting to the first element of the vector. A vectorized version of your function looks like:

```
data_manip <- function(x,gr){
    ifelse(grepl('goo|ug', gr) & x == 0.6, 1, x)
}
```

And gives the expected results:

```
> df%>%
+     group_by(type)%>%
+     mutate(percent_new=data_manip(percent,type))
# A tibble: 9 x 5
# Groups:   type [3]
  percent   type  smoke    sex percent_new
    <dbl> <fctr> <fctr> <fctr>       <dbl>
1     0.6   good  Visky   male         1.0
2     0.7   good   Wine   male         0.7
3     1.0   good   Wine female         1.0
4     0.5    bad  Visky   male         0.5
5     0.5    bad   Wine   male         0.5
6     1.0    bad   Wine female         1.0
7     0.4   ugly  Visky   male         0.4
8     0.6   ugly   Wine   male         1.0
9     1.0   ugly   Wine female         1.0
```

Use `ifelse` to get vectorized condition checking.

Comment: Really appreciated your solution and explanation! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a problem that `case_when` would be useful for.

Try this:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(new_percentage = case_when(type == "good" & percent == 0.6 ~ 1,
                                    type == "ugly" & percent == 0.6 ~ 1,
                                    TRUE ~ as.double(.$percent)))
```

Which gives:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 5
  percent   type  smoke    sex new_percentage
    <dbl> <fctr> <fctr> <fctr>          <dbl>
1     0.6   good  Visky   male            1.0
2     0.7   good   Wine   male            0.7
3     1.0   good   Wine female            1.0
4     0.5    bad  Visky   male            0.5
5     0.5    bad   Wine   male            0.5
6     1.0    bad   Wine female            1.0
7     0.4   ugly  Visky   male            0.4
8     0.6   ugly   Wine   male            1.0
9     1.0   ugly   Wine female            1.0
```